# How to create utf8mb4 database using python+MySQLdb, mysql commandline already shows utf8mb4, but database is still utf8

Tags: python, mysql, utf8mb4

I use Mysql5.6, Mysqldb_1.2.4, python_2.7.3 with win7 system. As the title says, I've modified  Mysql's configure file my.ini by changing charset.

After restarting mysql service, I use Mysql commandline:

[image]

When I create a database in mysql workbench, i use this collation--utf8mb4_unicode_ci:

[image]

However, I get this:

[image]

I really really wanna know how to create a utf8mb4 database, because I need the fix emoj characters inserted into database problem, which I think can be solved if I can create a utf8mb4 database.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem, by executing("SET NAMES utf8mb4") after creating connection with your database and acquiring cursor object.